# Non coherent Symbol Error Rate vs Es/N0

Tags: modulation, demodulation

Purpose:
Implementing a noncoherent M-ASK modulation ($M=2$) and comparing the results, $\mathrm{SER}$ vs. $E_s/N_0$, to the theoretical formula. The theoretical formula is not based on differential.

The problem statement:
Unfortunately, my simulation results are not the same as the theoretical.

Update: I added this line to Matlab code: `Sr_norm(i,Sr_norm(i,:)<0)=0;`
The reason : Theoritcally after an idal diode there is no negative signal. I had an improvement to make the simulated signal close to theoretical curve.
Update2: Unfortunately, the curves are `fs`-dependant. It becomes better since I chose fs = 10. Therefore, it was a failure.
[image]

Possible error:

I do not exactly know the source of error. But the problem can emerge from the way I am simulating, therefore, the method of simulation is firstly explained
:

The implementation:

1. Random symbols are made
2. Based on sampling frequency, `fs`, and symbol rate (symbol frequency), `fsymbol`, the number of samples per symbol are calculated.
3. Noise is added to the signal
   4.the duration of symbol and starting point is known. Therefore, I just average samples within one symbol to estimate what has been transmitted.
4. Then I just check the estimated mean value is closer to which symbol to interpret it.

@MBaz: I do not see the need for matched filter for my purpose. At the moment in results in simulation (Figure) is better than theory. So I really doubt that using matched filter will give me a result close to theory. Please let me know if I am making a mistake. I am not an expert in this area. Moreover, the formula is coming from: 
Ke-Lin Du, M. N. S. Swamy-Wireless Communication Systems_ From RF Subsystems to 4G Enabling Technologies (2010), page 194

In my opinion, the problem is how I am adding the noise. I read that the pdf of the symbols with noise should be like this, but the way I am adding the noise does not enforce this type of distribution on my symbols. I checked the histogram of my noisy symbols and the first symbol's distribution is not Rayleigh. Can it be the problem?

[[image]][3]

The code is in this post.

Any idea?

p.s. Although noncoherent seems easier than coherent, I still could not manage to simulate this type of modulation that is close to theory's trace.

```
clc;
clear all;
format long;

tic;
fs = 1;
fsymbol = 1;
N   = 10000000;      % total Number of symbols
M = 2;         % Number of Symbols
k = log2(M);    % Number of bits per Symbol
rep_nmbr = fs/fsymbol;

Es_N0_dB = 0:2:14;
Es_N0 = 10 .^ (Es_N0_dB/10);

alphabet = [0 1];
St = randsrc(1,N,alphabet);
St1symbol = St;

St_repmat = repmat(St,rep_nmbr,1);
St_repmat_reshape = reshape(St_repmat,1, rep_nmbr*N);

Es = 0.5;%sum(St_repmat_reshape.^2)/(length(St_repmat_reshape)*fsymbol);
%%
for i = 1:length(Es_N0_dB)
    N0 = Es./Es_N0(i); % the power spectral density of the noise, n0    
    pn = N0*fs/2; %the average noise power, pn, of noise having power spectral density „n0?, or sigma_n = N0*fs/2;
    n = 1*sqrt(pn)*randn(1,length(St_repmat_reshape));
    Sr_norm(i,:) = St_repmat_reshape + n;
    Sr_norm(i,Sr_norm(i,:)<0)=0;   % Erasing the values below zeros
end

%%
% Optimum Receiver Structure /or Decision regions comparison
% Decision Structure
Sr = Sr_norm; % No need for deNormalization : *sqrt(Eavg); % deNormalization of received signal
for i = 1:length(Es_N0_dB)
    % Decision bounderies
    % DM can be fixed or follows the Vopt based on theory
%      DM = 1/2*sqrt(1+2/db2pow(Es_N0_dB(i)));
    DM = 0.5;
    Sr1=reshape(squeeze(Sr(i,:)),rep_nmbr,N);
    Sr_mean(i,:) = mean(Sr1,1);

%     figure; 
%     h1 = histogram(Sr_mean(i,St1symbol==1),200);
%     figure;
%     h2 = histogram(Sr_mean(i,St1symbol==0),200);

    So_I(find(real(Sr_mean(i,:)) < DM(1)))           = alphabet(1);
    if (length(DM) > 1)
        for k = 2:length(DM)
            So_I(find((real(Sr_mean(i,:)) >  DM(k-1))&(real(Sr_mean(i,:)) < DM(k))))  = alphabet(k);
        end
    end
    So_I(find(real(Sr_mean(i,:)) > DM(length(DM))))  = alphabet(length(alphabet));
    So(i,:) = So_I;

    Pe2(i) = symerr(St1symbol,So(i,:))/(N);
    Pe2_analytic(i) = 1/2*(exp(-db2pow(Es_N0_dB(i))/2)+qfunc(sqrt(db2pow(Es_N0_dB(i)))));  %analytical result
end
'M=2  Simulation Completed'         % display in command window
Processing_Time = toc
%%

figure;
semilogy(Es_N0_dB, Pe2, '-*', Es_N0_dB, Pe2_analytic,'-o');
title('Pe: M-ASK, Analytical and Symulation result');
legend('M=2(simulation)', 'M=2(Analytic)');
xlabel('Es/N0 [dB]');
ylabel('Symbol Error Rate (SER)');
```

Comment: Your code is a bit hard to follow. Why do you define `Eb_N0` but then re-define it? Why do you subtract `10*log10(k)` from `Eb_N0`? Why do you multiply `sigma_n` by `fs`? Why do you have two identical variables `sigma_n` and `pn`? Please try to simplify your code, and add comments explaining what it's doing.

Comment: The Es_N0 and Eb_N0 are different.

Comment: The Es_N0 and Eb_N0 are different. Es_N0 is the energy symbol per N0. Eb_n0 is the energy bit per N0. Finally, i used Es_n0, because of the theoretical formula that I found. Sigma_n is redundant, I will remove it when I access my pc.

Comment: I double-checked but still managed to confuse `Eb` with `Es`, sorry about that... More questions: where do you do matched filtering, and where did you obtain the formula for the error rate? I don't think I had ever seen it.

Comment: This question asks why a MATLAB program is not giving "the right answer" without specifying what the OP thinks the right answer is. It would appear that there is considerable confusion in the OP's mind about the system since $M$-ASK with $M=2$ is binary ASK and so there is no distinction between $E_b$ and $E_s$. Furthermore, _noncoherent_ 2-ASK _generally_ uses differential encoding at the transmitter and differentially coherent demodulation at the receiver, and I don't see where this is accounted for in the program. I vote to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: "My results are as the same as theoretical". There are two traces in the figure generated by matlab; Simulation and analytical. These two are not the same. The analytical result is based on the simple noncoherent detection. I want to solve my problem with the simple M=2. I will focus on higher number for M. However, at the moment I just want to focus on Es_N0, therefore Eb_N0 is not needed.

Comment: As I asked before, please explain your noise variance calculation. Why do you multiply by `fs`? If you want `Es/N_0=x`, then `N_0=0.5/x` and the noise variance is `N_0/2`. Also, what is the is point of including rayleigh/rice fading distributions? As Dilip pointed out, where is the non-coherence happening in your code?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I didn't think that non-coherent ASK generally uses differential encoding; but could be mistaken..  I've seen this in non-coherent BSK as in that case there is ambiguity in the 0 and 180 degree states, and the "differential" allows us to demod by comparing successive symbols - but that is not the approach to demod non-coherent ASK. Also, I don't have as much of an issue with using "Symbols" even for binary modulation schemes; so $E_b = E_s$ seems fine, and in this case interchangeable, certainly not a reason to vote the question off-topic (??)

Comment: @MBaz : I multiplied by fs/2 because the whole noise power noise is N0*fs/2.

Comment: @MBaz : I believe you are pointing to the right direction. It seems the way that I am adding noise is not proper. 
However, I multiplied by fs/2 because the whole noise power noise is N0*fs/2. I am trying to make my plots independent of `fs`. As far as I know, by changing the increasing the number of per symbol, the curves are changed if we are comparing SER vs SNR. Therefore I am making the plots SER versus Es/N0. I am not 100% sure till now, I could achieve this goial or not.

Comment: Please, correct me if I am wrong. The reason that usually people represent SER vs Es/N0 or BER vs Eb/N0 rather than SER vs SNR is to make the plots independent of the number of samples per symbol.

Comment: @NightElf The SNR *must not* depend on the sampling frequency. Consider an analog implementation (where the sampling frequency tends to infinity); how do you deal with that? You're also still missing the fact that the SNR is measured *after* the matched filter.

Comment: @MBaz I did not mean SNR depends on the sampling frequency. What I mean is that: the number of samples per symbol should not be included in the quality of one type of modulation. Assume in my case, I have more than one sample per symbol to represent that symbol. Then I will make an average on those samples to interpret the received symbol, and the SER will decrease. If I do such simulation and compare it to another result that is based on less number of samples per symbol, then this comparison is not fair. 

Anyway, if I can do the averaging in this case, why do I need matched-filter?

Comment: @NightElf You should not be zeroing the negative samples as you are modeling (or should be modeling) the complex baseband signal. The diode will respond the the envelope (magnitude) regardless of phase, including 180°!  Is your noise a complex signal (meaning I + jQ where I and Q are independent AWGN signals?) at baseband as I suggested in the answer below?

Comment: Adding to my comment: Bit "0" would be just the complex noise, Bit "1" would be the complex noise with a DC offset. This is how you would model the complex baseband equivalent signal. If you do this you will see that the envelope (magitude) will have the histograms as you drew them (Rayleigh and Rician). And your non-coherent system would make bit decisions based on a threshold on the envelope.

Comment: @DanBoschen This is an old script. I implemented your method and it works. I can clearly see the Rayleigh and Rician histogram.
I will update everything tomorrow. Right now is 10:55pm and is too late. I have to go back home. Sorry

Comment: Good to hear and we are looking forward to seeing your results!

Comment: @DanBoschen What is the difference between 2-ASK and BPSK? I contend that there is no difference. What you seem to be talking about, and the MATLAB gobbledygook with Rayleigh and Rician noise etc is more commonly called OOK or On-Off Modulation, and not M-ASK with M=2.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - Yes, I was assuming he is doing On-Off keying (otherwise the Rayleigh and Rician distributions would not make sense).  But what is your point?  You don't think there was a reasonable opportunity here to help the OP productively?  I don't intend to offend you but I found your comments rather harsh (and I am sure you don't mean to be), and I hope that we can be a bit friendlier to people that take the time to come here with questions.

Answer (score 1):

I also had trouble following the code but the curves look very much like the expected difference between coherent and no-coherent ASK.  I suspect that you are not modeling the noise as a complex AWGN process and therefore emulating a coherent system, which is emulating what would happen if you were in complete synchronization with the transmitter's carrier. If you implement the noise as a complex AWGN signal (since the simulation is all done at baseband, which makes sense), and then use the envelope (magnitude) only of the signal to make your binary decision, you should get the analytic result as shown.  (If those are done as indicated, then it would suggest the manner in which signal or noise is measured is in error).

I can also provide insight into the Rayleigh and Rician distributions as drawn, which I believe to be correct for the case of Non-Coherent ASK:

The amplitude of a complex (key word there) Gaussian distributed noise process with zero mean will have a Rayleigh distribution. The amplitude of the same process with a non-zero mean will have a Ricean distribution. If the demodulation process is to detect the signal amplitude, and then make a decision, the histograms as shown are correct for establishing the expected error probability. This is consistent with Non-Coherent ASK, as in that appraoch we specifically demodulate by measuring (detecting) the amplitude of the envelope of our modulated waveform. This is in contrast to Corerent ASK which implies we have a local carrier that has be synchronized with the transmitter. In that approach demodulation is done with a product multiplier following an integration over a symbol period followed by a detector.  This latter approach is more complicated but would have an improved bit error rate vs SNR.  At higher SNR levels, the difference is slightly less than one dB.

To confirm the histograms measured, check that the noise being simulated is indeed complex AWGN, and make sure you are taking the histogram of the amplitude metric for the signal.

I am a big fan of this app note by HP  http://www.ab4oj.com/test/docs/5966-4008E.pdf which is specific to measuring noise with a spectrum analyzer, but give a good treatment on the noise processes involved related to this. Below is one graphic from that app note that provides intuitive insight into why we end up with a Rayleigh distribution. I will paraphrase their explanation in that the upper plot is showing samples of a complex white Gaussian noise process, and the radial grid corresponds to regions of constant amplitude. The histogram is the number of samples that appear in between each radial grid. As you approach the origin, the area becomes increasingly smaller and hence the histogram also approaches zero.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works.
It triggers some questions.

The only problem is that my results are dependent on "samples per symbol". I want my results to be independent of that parameter.

I will make a post and post the figures.

Comment: Super- See my comments in your post above, was concerned that you were zeroing the negative samples which is not representative of what a diode would do to your pass-band signal. (And of course you should be modelling baseband not passband): To model the "diode" at baseband you want a block that will return the envelope of the signal, which is simply the magnitude (independent of phase). That is the "non-coherent" part of your receiver.

Comment: Regarding your comment I think it is better phrased as being dependent on the time per symbol. (As it is really the time duration, independent of sampling rate). That said the SNR metric is normalized to be dB-Hz, and then becomes independent of the duration of each symbol.

Comment: @DanBoschen Thanks for the link to that app note -- that's a nice way to visualize the Rayleigh distribution. HP app notes are a treasure trove of practical information.

Comment: @MBaz Yes agreed! What was also very useful and interesting to me in this same app note is the expected under estimate (of -1.05 dB) if using the magnitudes to estimate power. (square of the average instead of average of the squares)

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain the way I would approach this problem. I'm basically following Blahut's "Digital Transmission of Information".

Let $\lbrace s_k(t)=s(t-kT_p)\rbrace,\,k\in\mathbb{N}$, be a set of orthonormal pulses. Let $\mathcal{A}=\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$, and $a_k \in \mathcal{A}$. The pulse rate is $R_p=1/T_p$. Then the 2-ASK (or, more accurately, OOK) signal can be written as $$v(t)=\left[\sum_k a_k s_k(t)\right]\cos(2\pi f_ct+\phi),$$ where the phase is relative to that of the local oscillator in the receiver. Ignoring noise, the complex baseband signal after quadrature demodulation is $$\left[\sum_k a_ks_k(t)\right]\cos\phi + j\left[ \sum_k a_ks_k(t)\right]\sin\phi.$$ After matched filtering, the signal is $$u(t)=\left[\sum_k a_kr_k(t)\right]\cos\phi + j\left[ \sum_k a_kr_k(t)\right]\sin\phi.$$ Since the pulses are orthonormal, then $$u(kTp) = a_k\cos\phi+ja_k\sin\phi,$$ and $$|u(kT_p)|=|a_k|.$$

I would start the simulation right after the matched filter. At that point, I know that the signal to noise ratio is $E_b/N_0=0.5/N_0$. So,

```
A = [0,1];                    % constellation
EbN0_dB = 6:12;               % SNR in dB
EbN0 = 10.^(EbN0_dB./10);
BER = zeros(1,length(EbN0));  % preallocate BER
nbit = 1e6;                   % how many symbols to simulate
Eb = 0.5;                     % average bit energy
thr = 0.5;                    % decision threshold

idx = 1;
for snr = EbN0
    errs = 0;
    n_std = sqrt(Eb/(2*snr));   % noise std dev
    for sym = 1:nbit
        a = A(randi(2));         % pick a symbol
        phi = 2*pi*rand();       % random phase
        ni = n_std*randn();      % in-phase noise
        nq = n_std*randn();      % quadrature noise
        ri = a*cos(phi)+ni;      % in-phase matched filter output
        rq = a*sin(phi)+nq;      % quad matched filter output
        u = sqrt(ri*ri + rq*rq); % magnitude
        if (a==1 && u<thr) || (a==0 && u>thr)
            errs = errs + 1;     % error found
        end
    end
    BER(idx) = errs/nbit;    % store BER
    idx = idx + 1;
end

% plot
Pb = 0.5*exp(-0.5*EbN0)+qfunc(sqrt(EbN0));  % Theoretical Pb (approx)
semilogy(EbN0_dB,BER,'o-',EbN0_dB,Pb,'x-');
legend('Simulation', 'Theory');
grid on;
```

With this code I get this result:

[image]